# Is there AUTO INCREMENT in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

I am trying to create a table with an auto-incrementing `primary key` in [Sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).  I am not sure if this is really possible, but I am hoping to only have to designate the other fields.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
  id integer primary key auto increment, 
  first_name varchar(20), 
  last_name varchar(20)
);
```

Then, when I add a value, I was hoping to only have to do:

```sql
INSERT INTO people VALUES ("John", "Smith");
```

Is this even possible?

I am running `sqlite3` under `cygwin` in Windows 7.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You get one for free, called ROWID.  This is in every SQLite table whether you ask for it or not.

If you include a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that column points at (is an alias for) the automatic ROWID column.

ROWID (by whatever name you call it) is assigned a value whenever you INSERT a row, as you would expect.  If you explicitly assign a non-NULL value on INSERT, it will get that specified value instead of the auto-increment.  If you explicitly assign a value of NULL on INSERT, it will get the next auto-increment value.

Also, you should try to avoid:

```
 INSERT INTO people VALUES ("John", "Smith");
```

and use

```
 INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES ("John", "Smith");
```

instead.  The first version is very fragile — if you ever add, move, or delete columns in your table definition the INSERT will either fail or produce incorrect data (with the values in the wrong columns).

Comment: ROWID isn't quite the same as a true autoincrement as the SAME value may be generated more than once. For example, with an empty table, inserting 3 rows gives the 3rd row a ROWID of 3 as expected. However insert 2 rows, delete the last and insert another, gives the 3rd inserted row a ROWID of 2, just as the 2nd row had. There is therefore an obvious serious problem if tables reference ROWIDs in a table where deletes occur and where deletes or ROWID nulling are not also done in the related tables.

Comment: In case it is not obvious from answer, you can use ROWID in your select statement e.g. `select rowid from people;`

Comment: @Nick just to complement your idea : so auto-increment is a safety measure. And we're not talking about two rows colliding in ROWID.

Comment: @Nick thank you for pointing that out, also `ROWID` isn't quite the same as a true autoincrement because you cannot reference `ROWID` as a foreign key to another table. I am finding creating tables `WITHOUT ROWID` and setting my own `id` column to `AUTOINCREMENT` is preferable just to be able to use it as a `FK`, as there doesn't seem to be a better way...

Comment: @ecoe Hmm, the without rowid docs (https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) say you can't do this? And I've also tried it : `Error while executing SQL query on database 'w': AUTOINCREMENT not allowed on WITHOUT ROWID tables`

Answer (score 124):

Yes, this is possible.  According to the [SQLite FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1):

> A column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will autoincrement.

You then have to pass `NULL` on that column when inserting. Example:

```
sqlite3 tmp.sqlite 'create table t(id integer primary key, i integer, j integer)'
sqlite3 tmp.sqlite 'insert into t values (NULL, 10, -10), (NULL, 20, -20)'
sqlite3 tmp.sqlite 'select * from t'
```

outputs:

```
1|10|-10
2|20|-20
```

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04, sqlite 3.40.1.

Comment: The caveat, as mentioned by Uku, and also explained in the documentation, is that you need to pass in a NULL for the ID in order for this to work.

Comment: You only *need* to use a NULL if you leave out the list of columns to INSERT — never a good practice.  If you specify the columns, you can simply leave out the auto-increment column and it will receive the next value.

Comment: Another caveat: write "INTEGER ..." exactly as given above. A shorthand "INT ..." will NOT work.

Comment: @MarcinWojnarski This is what I was missing, I assumed INT would work but the problem is to use INTEGER instead, otherwise the data will have the ID column values as None

Comment: it's not working even by passing NULL as param

Comment: @G.Ciardini I recommend you create your own question with actual details of what you are doing and the results you are getting rather than downvoting a perfectly reasonable answer to the question that was asked here.  The question here was "Is it possible?"  The answer is clear, regardless of your experience.  Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 60):

#### As of today — June 2018

---

Here is what [official SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) has to say on the subject (bold & italic are mine):

> 1. The **AUTOINCREMENT** keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>      disk I/O overhead and **should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>      usually not needed.**
> 2. In SQLite, a column with type **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the**
>      **ROWID** (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed
>      integer.
> 3. On an INSERT, **if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not**
>      **explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an**
>      **unused integer, *usually* one more than the largest ROWID currently in**
>      **use.** This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>      keyword is used.
> 4. If the **AUTOINCREMENT** keyword appears **after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY**, that
>      changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to **prevent the reuse**
>      **of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database.** In other words, the
>      purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
>      previously deleted rows.

Answer (score 17):

SQLite AUTOINCREMENT is a keyword used for auto incrementing a value of a field in the table. We can auto increment a field value by using AUTOINCREMENT keyword when creating a table with specific column name to auto incrementing it.

The keyword AUTOINCREMENT can be used with INTEGER field only.
Syntax:

The basic usage of AUTOINCREMENT keyword is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
   column1 INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
   .....
   columnN datatype,
);
```

For Example See Below:
Consider COMPANY table to be created as follows:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE TB_COMPANY_INFO(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
   NAME           TEXT      NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT       NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);
```

Now, insert following records into table TB_COMPANY_INFO:

```
INSERT INTO TB_COMPANY_INFO (NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES ( 'MANOJ KUMAR', 40, 'Meerut,UP,INDIA', 200000.00 );
```

Now Select the record

```
SELECT *FROM TB_COMPANY_INFO
ID      NAME            AGE     ADDRESS             SALARY
1       Manoj Kumar     40      Meerut,UP,INDIA     200000.00
```

Answer (score 13):

Have you read this? [How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

```
INSERT INTO people
VALUES (NULL, "John", "Smith");
```

Always insert NULL as the id.

Comment: The NULL on INSERT is *only* required if you don't specify the list of columns to INSERT (in which case, you need a number of values exactly matching the number of columns and must use NULL as a placeholder).  But doing an INSERT without specifying the list of columns is never good practice.  If you specify the list of columns, just leave out both the autoincrement column and the NULL value, and you'll get the result you expect.

Answer (score 6):

One should not specify `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword near `PRIMARY KEY`.
Example of creating autoincrement primary key and inserting:

```
$ sqlite3 ex1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room(room_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, home_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO room(name, home_id) VALUES ('test', 'home id test');

INSERT INTO room(name, home_id) VALUES ('test 2', 'home id test 2');

SELECT * FROM room;
```

will give:

```
1|test|home id test
2|test 2|home id test 2
```

Comment: *Why* should we "not specify AUTOINCREMENT keyword near PRIMARY KEY" ?  Is it wrong? Unnecessary? Something else?

Answer (score 5):

Beside rowid, you can define your own auto increment field but it is not recommended. It is always be better solution when we use rowid that is automatically increased.

> The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

Read [here](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for detailed information.

Comment: apparently rowid isn't always automatically increased, see the comment by Nick

Comment: Not true. Auto increment is better in some respects, since it will not reuse IDs - a pretty important requirement for many systems.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is correct, but the correct syntax for 'auto increment' should be without space:

```
CREATE TABLE people (id integer primary key autoincrement, first_name string, last_name string);
```

(Please also note that I changed your varchars to strings. That's because SQLite internally transforms a varchar into a string, so why bother?)

then your insert should be, in SQL language as standard as possible:

```
INSERT INTO people(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (null, 'john', 'doe');
```

while it is true that if you omit id it will automatically incremented and assigned, I personally prefer not to rely on automatic mechanisms which could change in the future.

A note on autoincrement: although, as many pointed out, it is not recommended by SQLite people, I do not like the automatic reuse of ids of deleted records if autoincrement is not used. In other words, I *like* that the id of a deleted record will never, ever appear again.

HTH

Comment: In this respect I totally share what O'Rooney says.

Comment: And if you try to check the AI box in DB Browser for SQLite's Modify Table dialog, it won't save that if there are records in the table already.  My work-around was to do an Export "everything" and modify the .sql file's specification of the PK to add AUTOINCREMENT, then use that file for an Import back into the database.  Not only did it preserve the AI, but it preserved the PK values as they were even when they did not start at 1.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a bit late.
 My purpose for this answer is for everyone's reference should they encounter this type of challenge with SQLite now or in the future and they're having a hard time with it.

Now, looking back at your query, it should be something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE people (id integer primary key autoincrement, first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(20));
```

It works on my end. Like so,

[image]

Just in case you are working with SQLite, I suggest for you to check out [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). Works on different platforms as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, you can auto-increment with and without [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) as shown below. *`AUTOINCREMENT` must be used with [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) otherwise there is error:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  name TEXT           -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- No AUTOINCREMENT
  name TEXT
);
```

And, `AUTOINCREMENT` can avoid to reuse the deleted numbers unless explicitly specifying them while no `AUTOINCREMENT` cannot according to [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). *[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77205670/autoincrement-vs-no-autoincrement-in-sqlite) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77205670/autoincrement-vs-no-autoincrement-in-sqlite/77205671#77205671) explain the difference between `AUTOINCREMENT` and no `AUTOINCREMENT`.