# Python SQLite3 AUTOINCREMENT Error

Tags: python, sqlite, auto-increment, bottle

I am making a shopping list program for my mum with Python, SQLite3 and Bottle,
I am making a table to put all my items into but the `item_id` with `AUTOINCREMENT` on the column it doesn't work:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE categories (
            category_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            category_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE products (
            item_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            item_category_id INTEGER NOT NULL)""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE shopping_products (
            item_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,
            item_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            item_category_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
            item_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
            item_date INTEGER NOT NULL)""")
```

On the `shopping_products` table the `AUTOINCREMENT` keep returning this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905859/is-there-an-auto-increment-in-sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

1. Are you sure you need `AUTOINCREMENT`? It's [not normally required in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

   > 1. The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.
   > 2. In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed integer.
   > 3. On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.
   > 4. If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.

   As long as you're not worried about reusing ROWIDs from previously deleted rows `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` should be fine.
2. If you do want to use `AUTOINCREMENT` with SQLite it must be on an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, e.g.

   ```
   item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
   ```
3. Your `shopping_products` table has a `TEXT PRIMARY KEY` on `item_name`.

   You can't have two primary keys, so if you want `item_id` to have `AUTOINCREMENT` you'll need to stop using `item_name` as your primary key. An item name would be a strange primary key anyway.

Comment: For this particular case in question I guess this from the same doc would better answer:    

`Because AUTOINCREMENT keyword changes the behavior of the ROWID selection algorithm, AUTOINCREMENT is not allowed on WITHOUT ROWID tables or on any table column other than INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Any attempt to use AUTOINCREMENT on a WITHOUT ROWID table or on a column other than the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column results in an error.`