# AUTOINCREMENT vs No AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, auto-increment, database-table

I put and did not put `AUTOINCREMENT` for `id` in `person` table as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  name TEXT            # ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, # No AUTOINCREMENT
  name TEXT
);
```

Then, I added 3 rows to `person` table as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO person (name) 
VALUES ('John'), ('David'), ('Lisa');
```

Finally, I got the exactly same 3 rows from `person` table both incrementing the number for `id` by one as shown below:

```
.headers on  
.mode box
SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
│ 3  │ Lisa  │
└────┴───────┘
```

So, what is the difference between `AUTOINCREMENT` and no `AUTOINCREMENT` for `id` in `person` table?

Answer (score 1):

`AUTOINCREMENT` can avoid to reuse the deleted numbers unless explicitly specifying them while no `AUTOINCREMENT` cannot according to [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

For example, you put `AUTOINCREMENT` for `id` in `person` table and it has 3 rows as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  name TEXT           -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
);

SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
│ 3  │ Lisa  │
└────┴───────┘
```

Then, you delete the row where `id` is `3`, then get 2 rows from `person` table as shown below:

```
DELETE FROM person where id = 3;

SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
└────┴───────┘
```

Now, you add one row to `person` table, then `4` is added to `id` as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO person (name) values ('Anna');

SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
│ 4  │ Anna  │ <- Here
└────┴───────┘
```

In addition, if you add one row to `person` table by explicitly setting `3` to `id`, then `3` is added to `id` as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO person (id, name) values (3, 'Anna');
                  # ↑↑              # ↑
SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
│ 3  │ Anna  │ <- Here
└────┴───────┘
```

Next for example, you do not put `AUTOINCREMENT` for `id` in `person` table and it has 3 rows as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- No AUTOINCREMENT
  name TEXT
);

SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
│ 3  │ Lisa  │
└────┴───────┘
```

Then, you delete the row where `id` is `3`, then get 2 rows from `person` table as shown below:

```
DELETE FROM person where id = 3;

SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
└────┴───────┘
```

Now, you add one row to `person` table, then `3` is added to `id` as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO person (name) values ('Anna');

SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
├────┼───────┤
│ 1  │ John  │
│ 2  │ David │
│ 3  │ Anna  │ <- Here
└────┴───────┘
```