# Error using System.Data.Linq.Mapping and auto incrementing the primary key in a sqlite db

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm using `SQLite` and `System.Data.Linq.Mapping`. I'm having an issue with the `id` `AUTOINCREMENT` field when using the linq mapping attribute `IsDbGenerated = true`.

Syntax to create my table. I've tried this with/without the `AUTOINCREMENT`

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable] ([id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,[title] TEXT  NULL)
```

My TABLE class:

```
[Table(Name = "TestTable")]
public class TestTable
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated =true)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I call it. When it goes to submit I get a error, I'll paste the error below this example. One thing to note is if I take out the `IsDbGenerated =true` above and enter the `id` manually it does insert fine, but I'd like it to `AUTOINCREMENT` and for some reason the `IsDbGenerated=true` is killing the insert. Looking for some guidance.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = @"DbLinqProvider=Sqlite;Data Source = c:\pathToDB\test.s3db";
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    DataContext db = new DataContext(connection);
    db.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\pathToDB\mylog.log") { AutoFlush = true };

    var com = db.GetTable<TestTable>();
    com.InsertOnSubmit(new TestTable {title = "asdf2" });
    try {
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode);
        Console.WriteLine(e.HelpLink);
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        Console.WriteLine(e.TargetSite);
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    foreach (var TestTable in com)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestTable: {0} {1}", TestTable.id, TestTable.title);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Error message:

> SQL logic error or missing database\r\nnear \"SELECT\": syntax error

Stack trace:

> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String
>   strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String&
>   strRemain)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd,
>   CommandBehavior behave)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject
>   item)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject
>   item)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()\r\n
>   at SqlLinq.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 29"

Here is what I'm seeing in the log output:

```
INSERT INTO [company]([title])
VALUES (@p0)

SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]
-- @p0: Input String (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [asdf2]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.6.81.0

SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[title]
FROM [company] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.6.81.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the SQLite documentation ([A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will AUTOINCREMENT.](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)) just remove `AUTOINCREMENT` in your Table creation,  Writing `integer primary key` is enough. ***SQLite will automatically increment your `ids`***:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [TestTable] ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , [title] TEXT)";
```

Also you don't need to set `IsDbGenerated = true` in your `TestTable` class and don't enter the `id` manually, it does insert fine just by inserting `title`:

```
com.InsertOnSubmit(new TestTable { title = "asdf2" });//will automatically increment id.
```

***Edit:*** Your `TestTable` should look like this now:

```
[Table(Name = "TestTable")]
public class TestTable
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

The result in SQLite Manager:

[image: The result]

Comment: I tried it this way just now. I recreated the table with your sql example and removed the IsDbGenerated property. It does enter the first record adding a 0 for the id. 2nd attempt fails with the same error as my description. This is the same behavior i was seeing before.

Comment: Change your id to `Nullable` like this:`public int? id { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field

**Short answer**: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

**Longer answer:** If you declare a column of a table to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if the table is empty. Or, if the largest existing integer key 9223372036854775807 is in use then an unused key value is chosen at random. For example, suppose you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  b INTEGER
);
```

With this table, the statement

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL,123);
```

is logically equivalent to saying:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES((SELECT max(a) FROM t1)+1,123);
```

There is a function named `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` which will return the integer key for the most recent insert operation.

> Note that the integer key is one greater than the largest key that was
>   in the table just prior to the insert. The new key will be unique over
>   all keys currently in the table, but it might overlap with keys that
>   have been previously deleted from the table. To create keys that are
>   unique over the lifetime of the table, add the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword
>   to the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` declaration. Then the key chosen will be
>   one more than the largest key that has ever existed in that table. If
>   the largest possible key has previously existed in that table, then
>   the `INSERT` will fail with an SQLITE_FULL error code.

References :

**[Autoincrement in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)**

**[How to create Autoincrement Field ?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)**

**[SO post dealing with Autoincrement in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149635/dealing-with-sqlite-autoincrement-column-mapping-in-linqtosql)**

Comment: It's easily possible i'm missing above but I don't see a ref to how to do this with linq. I'm able to handle auto increment with no issues when using straight sql and not using linq. (System.Data.Linq.Mapping

Answer (score 1):

SQLLite doesn't work with Linq commands for autoincrement values
This command produces error

```
SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]
```

You have only 2 way:

1. Do not use Linq for SQLLite. Use some third party solutions, or your
   own commands.
2. Use another ways to inrement your ID, as it was written by [utility]

The first one better, because there are other examples of SQL statements being passed to sqlite via Linq which aren't valid.